# What exactly does the lb instruction do?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have an exam coming up, and one of the practice problems was:

> Assume that `$t0` contains the value `0x12121212` and `$t1` contains
>   the address `0x1000000`.
>
> Assume that the memory data, starting from address `0x1000000` is:
>   `88 77 66 55`.
>
> What will be the value of `$t0` after the following code is executed:
>
> ```
> lb $t0, 0($t1)
> ```
>
> a) `0x00000088` b) `0x88121212` c) `0xffffff88` d) `0x12121288`

The answer I gave was `a`, because the byte that the `lb` instruction will read (by my understanding of what the instruction does) is 88. The 88 will then be stored in `$t0`, thus the value will be `0x00000088`. But the answer given was `c`. I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding about how `lb` works - can someone please explain why the answer is `c`?

Comment: Looks like sign extension to me

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought so too, but I don't at all understand why the sign extension was done - could you explain in an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer would be `c) 0xffffff88`. The `lb` instructions sign-extends the byte into a 32-bit value. I.e. the most significant bit (msb) is copied into the upper 24 bits.

0x88 == 0b10001000, i.e. the msb is 1. So the upper 24 bits will be 0b111111111111111111111111 == 0xffffff.

Answer (score 5):

The `lb` instruction loads a byte from memory and `sign extends` to the size of the register.  The `lbu` instruction does the same without sign extension (unsigned).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Integer

Most computers, MIPS included, use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed values though there are [other ways to encode the sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), floating point is usually represented in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) format which uses signed magnitude.  An integer signed value can be represented in any number of bits, for example

- a `char` in C is 8-bits and can represent -128 to +127
- a `short` in C is 16-bits and can represent -32768 to +32767
- etc

In two's complement the most significant bit can be used to determine the sign of the number, a `'1'` means it is negative, and a `'0'` means it is positive.

The number 0x88, when interpreted as an 8-bit two's complement number is negative 0x78 or -120 decimal.  When represented in 32-bits two's complement this is 0xFFFFFF88.  There are a couple of ways to remember how to compute the two's complement of a number:

- take the one's complement of the number (invert every bit) and add '1', or
- go from least significant bit towards most significant bit (right to left), skip over every '0' and the first '1' you encounter, invert every bit after that

To sign extend a 8-bit to 32-bits just look at the most significant bit (bit 7) and copy that bit to bits 8 thru 31... This follows from the definition of two's complement.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just information I could have gotten off Wikipedia, and the same information written in my textbook - I still don't understand why the answer to the problem in my question is `c`.

Comment: @Daniel, amdn told you your answer and even highlighted the relevant part.  You should read up on sign extension.

Comment: @CarlNorum Maybe my title is misleading, but I didn't think "Why is the answer c?" to be an appropriate title, though it is my actual question. I suspected sign extension as well (the preceding `0xffffff` was clear enough) but I don't understand why the sign extension was done. Copy-pasting the standard definition of the `lb` instruction isn't very helpful..

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at.  Sign extension is explicitly part of the `lb` instruction.  If you didn't want sign extension, you'd use `lbu`.

Comment: @CarlNorum My problem was that I didn't understand how the sign-extension was done - Michael explained to me that since the MSB of 0x88 is 1, the other 24 bits will also be 1.