# incorrect loading of value from memory to register in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I do a project in mips in mars simulator and my program hangs on syscall due to the odd behavior.

I want to store a given char buffer to file and pass to syscall the appropriate length of it.

```
.data
line_length: .space 4
# ...

.text
# ...

lb  $t0, line_length
li  $v0, 15
lb  $a0, io_descriptors+4
la  $a1, output_line
move    $a2, $t0
syscall
```

The value stored in line_length is 0x80. And that is indeed the case also just before and after the lb instruction. The value in $t0 after lb is 0xffffff80 though, for a reason beyond my comprehension. As the number is negative, the syscall fails. What could be the reason that $t0 doesn't store 0x80 value? How can I fix it?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with MIPS, but I think what's going on is that the byte value 0x80 is being sign-extended to 32 bits. I.e. it is a signed byte load.  0x80 is the8 bit two's complement value -128. The MSB is 1, so it is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading a single byte (8 bits) into a register (32 bits on MIPS), the value needs to be *extended* to fill the remaining 24 bits. There are two options:

- **Zero extend** which fills the remaining upper bits with zeros. This makes sense when the value is *unsigned*.
- [**Sign extend**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) which fills the remaining upper bits with a copy of the most-significant bit. This makes sense when the value is *signed*.

`lb` loads a single byte, and *sign-extends* it before putting it into the 32-bit register. Since you're reading `0x80`, the most-significant bit is a 1, so the 32-bit result is `0xFFFFFF80`.

Since you've declared `line_length` to be 4 bytes, you want to use `lw` which loads a full 32-bit word (with no extension).  Just make sure you're being consistent with the instructions you use to access and manipulate this variable.

See also:

- [What exactly does the lb instruction do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836338/what-exactly-does-the-lb-instruction-do)
- [MIPS: load and store](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/load.html)
- [MIPS Architecture](http://www.citidel.org/bitstream/10117/1014/1/MIPS+Architecture.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for a great and fast answer. The whole project was mostly on chars so that I became too used to lb. Didn't know though that sign extension works that way and got confused.