# How to sign extend a two's complement number given in the program arguments in mips (assembly)

Tags: assembly, binary, mips, twos-complement, sign-extension

I am trying to sign extend a two's complement number that I get from the program arguments in mips. How would I do this?

Comment: What are the size of the argument and the size of the output?

Comment: The argument is an 8-bit binary number in two's complement. The sign extended is 32 bits as I will eventually put this into a hexadecimal form.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to take advantage of the MIPS `sra` instruction, this instruction performs an [*arithmetic* right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) - it shifts right a register while shifting in the sign bit.
By putting the 8-bit value to the far left (read in the most significant position) with a `sll` we make its sign bit coincide with the register sign bit, then we use `sra`:

```
#Assume $a0 is a) 0x40 b) 0x80
sll $a0, $a0, 24      #a) $a0 = 0x40000000 b) $a0 = 0x80000000
sra $a0, $a0, 24      #a) $a0 = 0x00000040 b) $a0 = 0xffffff80
```

---

For values in memory, the [`lb`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836338/what-exactly-does-the-lb-instruction-do) will load a byte sign extending it (contrary to `lbu`).

---

Since the [release 2 of the MIPS32 ISA](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mips/mips32_instruction_set#Release_2), the `seb rt, rs` instruction that sign-extends the least significant byte of a GP register.

Comment: How would I be able to print this to the console?

Comment: @wolverinexci That depends on your execution environment. Both MARS and SPIM have system calls to print numbers. If you are having trouble with it, search this site for possible questions and if none satisfies you, try asking a new one. Since this is not a forum, we don't really engage in a ping-pong of questions and answers, each question must be self-contained as its answer must be.

Comment: I did do a syscall after this. I did li $v0, 4 la $a0, ($a0 ( i guess this is the location of the address)) syscall but I did have an out of range error.

Comment: MIPS32r2 added a `seb dst,src` (sign-extend-byte) instruction.  See https://godbolt.org/z/D7H2Q3.  gcc uses it with `-march=mips32r2`, but otherwise uses left/right shifts like you show.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you very much! It's a very nice add-on!

Comment: Describing MIPS32r2 as "revision 2 of the ISA" is ambiguous with "MIPS II".  The whole MIPS32 / MIPS64 thing didn't happen until 1998 when Silicon Graphics sold off MIPS and the ISA focused on embedded.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I was reading the MIPS history when found this ambiguity and come back to fix it . Thank for your comment anyway :)