# MIPS Allocation of Space

Tags: arrays, mips

My program takes an integer from 0-100 then takes the summation of x=0 to the integer taken from x*4. but after 31 and into 32 it's incorrect and starts subtracting value. I believe it is due to the array and space but I don't know. Any suggestions?

```
#Daniel Nelson

#Variable Declaration
.data
promptX: .asciiz "Input a number between 0 - 100: "
outMessageError: .asciiz "The number you entered was not between 0-100"
outMessageAdd: .asciiz "The sum of quadruple integers from 0 to "
outMessageIs: .asciiz " is "
X: .word 0

array: .word 400


#---------------------------------------------------
#section that declares methods for program
.text 
main:
    #output X
    li $v0, 4         #load 4 into $v0 to indicate a print string
    la $a0, promptX    #load the address of the greeting into $a0
    syscall       #"prints prompt

    #input X
    li $v0, 5    #takes input from user
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0    #stores in $s0
    sw $s0, X


    #1 = true

    #checks to see if number is greater than 100 and if less than goes to elseHundo
    blt $s0,101,ElseHundo
    #output Message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, outMessageError
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    ElseHundo:
        #cecks to see if number is less than 0 and if greater goes to elseZero
        bgt $s0, $zero, ElseZero
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, outMessageError
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
        ElseZero:
            #checks to see if number is equal to 0, if it is goes to ElseExit
            beq $s0,$zero, ElseExit
            li $t1, 0
            li $t2, 0
                loop:
                    bgt $t1, $s0, exitLoop#if counter resches x then exit            
                    sll $t2, $t1, 2 #sets t2 equal to counter*4
                    sb $t2,array($t1) #sets array[t1] = t2
                    #adds all numbers in the array
                    addi $t1,$t1, 1 #adds 1 to t1
                    j loop #jumps back to start of loop
                exitLoop: 
                    li $t1, 0   #counter
                    li $t2, 0   #value in array
                    li $t3, 0   #total
                    
                    LoopAdd:
                        bgt $t1, $s0, ExitLoopAdd
                        lb $t2, array($t1)
                        add $t3, $t3, $t2
                        addi $t1, $t1, 1
                        j LoopAdd
                    ExitLoopAdd:
                        #output Message
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, outMessageAdd
                syscall
                li $v0,1
                la $a0, ($s0)
                syscall
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, outMessageIs
                syscall
                li $v0,1
                la $a0, ($t3)
                syscall
                
                        
            ElseExit:
                li $v0, 10
                syscall
```

When 31 is input, it spits out 1984 which is correct. When 32 is input, it spits out 1856. When 40 is input, it spits out 976. When 50 is input, it spits out 236. 55 = 16 ; 56 = -16; 60 = -104 ; 62 = -124 ; 63 = -128 ; 64 = -128 ; 65 = -124 ; 70 = -44 ; 80 = 416 so it counts up to 2k or so, then counts down after to -128 then counts up again.

ok ok ok
so i ran through it step by step
as soon as i hit 32, it went from 124 to to -128 for what number to add
BUT when i was adding numbers to the array, all the numbers were right....
then it starts adding -128, -124, -120, -116...why does it do this?

(I was working on a project for my class, and he asked for it this way. Why? Idk, I hate this professor...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does the lb instruction do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836338/what-exactly-does-the-lb-instruction-do)

Comment: Why do you need an array for that? You don't even need a loop. The answer is just `x * (x+1) * 2`. And even if you do it in a loop, why do you need an array? You just need a counter and a register where you sum up the values, like you do when you sum up your array. No need for pushing the values in an intermediate array.

Comment: Are you using signed bytes for storage?  Try `lbu` that should get you 2x further.  Then try using words for storage instead of bytes.